XSLT error FODC0002 although path seems correct
I am using XSLT 2 (Saxon HE 10.9).
I have the following directory tree:
Project
- index.xml
- Classes
  - MyClassA
    - MyClassA.xml 

I am transforming MyClassA.xml into a new file format.
Here a sample code:
<xsl:for-each select="properties/property[type = document('../../index.xml',.)/classes/class/id]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="display_name"/>
</xsl:for-each>

I'm getting the following error:
FODC0002  Exception thrown by URIResolver resolving `../../index.xml` against
`file:///D:/Project/Classes/MyClassA'. Found while atomizing the second operand of '='

I don't really understand why I'm getting this error, the path seems correct.
The path should be file:///D:/Project/Classes/MyClassA/../../index.xml, which is the same as file:///D:/Project/index.xml, and my file is indeed located here.
What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT:
Here is the C# code that transform the file as asked in comments:
RawDestination destination = new RawDestination();
using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
{
    XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();
    using (MessageListener msg = new MessageListener(transformer))
    {
        msg.OnError = () => { success = false; };
        transformer.BaseOutputUri = new Uri(outputFile);
        transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile)));
        transformer.Run(destination); // this will set HasError if an xsl:message contains "error:"
    }
}


The base URI used by Saxon seems to be file:///D:/Project/Classes/MyClass, if I interpret part of the error message correctly. How exactly do you run the transformation, can you share the code to allow us to see where the base URI of the input XML is set?

For me, with Saxon 10 and 12 resolve-uri('../../index.xml', 'file:///D:/Project/Classes/MyClass') gives file:/D:/index.xml. There is also some discrepancy between your directory tree with MyClassA vs MyClass in your error message.

@MartinHonnen Sorry, I've changed MyClass to MyClassA, this was a mistake when changing names from my real error message (to simplify and anonymize).
Also I've edited my question with the C# code in the program that transform the files.

@MartinHonnen Okay, it seems using ../index.xml instead is working (not throwing error anymore). That seems weird but why not.

It is a common mistake to use the directory URI as the base URI, use the URI of the input file itself i.e. transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(inputFile));.

XSLT is really all about "context" of the current XML of the xml data itself and the related selectors - try to keep it simple to match in context

@MartinHonnen Yes new Uri(inputFile) seems to work. Thank you very much! I will accept your answer if you write one. I'll write one myself if you don't want.

The code you have to set the base URI of the input stream to the directory of the input file is the culprit i.e. you have
transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile)));

but need
transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(inputFile));

If you set the base URI to the parent directory and then use a relative URI with ../../ you are ending up in file:/D:/ for your sample data.

This works great, the relative paths are now correct, thank you very much!
